# My model is not reflecting any light / looks dark

Tags: lighting, shadows, reflection

In the image I have 2 objects, the only difference between the two is that the one on the right is fully unwrapped while the one on the left is the default with no changes safe for the texture to compare the colors.

Both models have the same texture image and no nodes were modified in the process and yet the one with the unwrapped map looks completely dark as if it is reflecting no light at all. Could you help me understand what happened and if there's a way to fix it?

[image: side by side comparisonn. Left Original obj with texture, Right, Unwrapped model with the same texture.]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem you may find with some imported files, you need to go in the *Properties* panel > *Objec*t Data > *Geometry* Data, and close *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea how it activated in the first place, but it's back to normal =D. Thank you for taking the time to look at it! =)

Comment: As I told it's a problem of normals with some imported objects, don't ask me more  ;)